# how to getExecutionsByCycleId more then 50 i have 250 TC in zephyr jira

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jira-zephyr

how to **getExecutionsByCycleId** more then 50 i have 250 TC, i need to get execution id so can update tc status with java selenium code.

I tried offset and size but it does not work.

Can i increase that size return more then 50.

hw to **getExecutionsByCycleId** more then 50 i have 250 TC, i need to get execution id so can update tc status with java selenium code.

I tried offset and size but it does not work.

Can i increase that size return more then 50.